# Entity Framework Track Changes of Entity Property?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Appreciate your help and guidance, please.

I have an Entity Candidate which I am able to track changes, however, the Entity itself shows `Unchanged` even though I have updated the Property `FirstName` of the Entity Candidate. The `ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView` shows `'AVS' Originally 'AVS123'`

So what I am doing wrong here? why the status of the `Candidate {Id: 13}` still shows Unchanged.

```
private void txtFirstName_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtCandidateId.Text);
        Candidate candidate = _dbContext.Candidates.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);

        candidate.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;

        Debug.WriteLine(_dbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Candidate {Id: 13} Unchanged
  Id: 13 PK
  DateOfBirth: '7/15/2022 12:00:00 AM'
  Email: '1234@gmail.com'
  ExpectedJoinDate: <null>
  FirstName: 'AVS' Originally 'AVS123'
  Gender: 'Male'
  LastName: 'Dev'
```

Comment: Try : context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
immediately before your writeline.
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Thank you that works. Do you know how I can actually determine the actual member that was edited? Please add an answer.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments. Since this question has no answers yet, you can edit it and explain what you actually want. But please also note that there are more questions (and answers) on how to detect changed properties in EF.

Comment: @GertArnold I can update the question. I have asked Chris to add an answer as hes answered in the comment. Also when I do ask another question related to the question I get hammered by moderated, so it is becoming annoying. So not sure what to do anymore!